# Need Three Highest Values (or more, if tied) of PHP Array and Their Location?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array. I'd like to get the three highest values of the array, but also remember which part of the array it was in.

For example, if my array is [12,3,7,19,24], my result should be values 24,19,12, at locations 4, 0, 3.

How do I do that? The first part is easy. Getting the locations is difficult.

Secondly, I'd like to also use the top three OR top number after three, if some are tied. So, for example, if I have [18,18,17,17,4], I'd like to display 18, 18, 17, and 17, at location 0,1,2,3.

Does that make sense? Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: If you have the values, why not store those on another vector. Then use a for loop to search for them and when it matches just get the index?

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you be there using [asort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)?

For example:

```
<?php
$list = [4,18,18,17,17];

// Sort maintaining indexes.
asort($list);

// Slice the first 3 elements from the array.
$top3 = array_slice($list, -3, null, true);

// Results in: [ 1 => 18, 2 => 18, 3 => 17 ]
```

Comment: `asort`, yes. But it should be `array_slice($list, -3, null, true);` to get the _greatest_ three elements, (and the fourth param `true` will maintain the keys again.)

Comment: Fair point, edited the `array_slice()` example. I rarely use the last parameters, but the `$preserve_keys` is quite essential ;).

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use arsort

```
function getMyTop($list, $offset, $top) {
    arsort($list);
    return array_slice($list, $offset, $top, true);
}

$myTop = getMyTop($list, 0, 3);
$myNextTop = getMyTop($list, 3, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need!

```
<?php
$array = array(12,3,7,19,24);
$array_processed = array();
$highest_index = 0;

while($highest_index < 3)
{
    $max = max($array);
    $index = array_search($max,$array);
    $array_processed[$index] = $max;
    unset($array[$index]);

    $highest_index++;
}

print_r($array_processed);
?>
```

You will get Index as well as the value! You just have to define how many top values you want! Let me know if it's what you want!

Answer (score 0):

```
function top_three_positions($array){

  // Sort the array from max to min
  arsort($array);

  // Unset everything in  sorted array after the first three elements
  $count = 0;
  foreach($array as $key => $ar){
    if($count > 2){
       unset($array[$key]);
    }
    $count++;
  }

  // Return array with top 3 values with their indexes preserved.
  return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to determine how many elements your top-three-with-ties will have, after applying `arsort`:

```
function getTop($arr, $num = 3) {
    arsort($arr);
    foreach(array_values($arr) as $i => $v) {
        if ($i >= $num && $v !== $prev) return array_slice($arr, 0, $i, true);
        $prev = $v;
    }
    return $arr;
}

// Sample input
$arr = [4,18,17,6,17,18,9];
$top = getTop($arr, 3);
print_r($top); // [5 => 18, 1 => 18, 4 => 17, 2 => 17]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public function getTopSortedThree(array $data, $n = 3, $asc = true)
{
    if ($asc) {
        uasort($data, function ($a, $b) { return $a>$b;});
    } else {
        uasort($data, function ($a, $b) { return $a<$b;});
    }
    $count = 0;
    $result = [];
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $result[] = $data[$key];
        $count++;
        if ($count >= $n){
            break;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Send `false` for `desc` order and nothing for `asc` order

Send `$n` with number of top values you want.

This functionality doesn't losing keys.

Answer (score 0):

This task merely calls for a descending sort, retention of the top three values, and in the case of values after the third-positioned value being equal to the third value, retain these as well.

After calling `rsort()`, call a `for()` loop starting from the fourth element (`[3]`).  If the current value is not equal to the value in the third position, stop iterating, and isolate the elements from the front of the array to the previous iteration's index.  Done.

p.s. If the input array has 3 or fewer elements, the `for()` loop is never entered and the whole (short) array avoids truncation after being sorted.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/V3lAi))

```
$array = [18, 17, 4, 18, 17, 16, 17];

rsort($array);

for ($i = 3, $count = count($array); $i < $count; ++$i) {
    if ($array[2] != $array[$i]) {
        $array = array_slice($array, 0, $i);
        break;
    }
}
var_export($array);
```

Because the loop purely finds the appropriate finishing point of the array (`$i`), this could also be compacted to: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/bM2JT))

```
rsort($array);
for ($i = 3, $count = count($array); $i < $count && $array[2] === $array[$i]; ++$i);
var_export(array_slice($array, 0, $i));
```

Or slightly reduced further to: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZkFRR))

```
rsort($array);
for ($i = 3; isset($array[2], $array[$i]) && $array[2] === $array[$i]; ++$i);
var_export(array_slice($array, 0, $i));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 18,
  1 => 18,
  2 => 17,
  3 => 17,
  4 => 17,
)
```